# C# Changing Text from a Label with a Button from a UserControl

Tags: c#

sorry for that stupid question.
I try to learn C# myself.

I try to change Text from a Label in my Form with a Button from a UserControl.

In my Form.cs

```
public void AddPizzaFirst_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Warenkorb.Text = "Test";
}
```

and this is in my Usercontrol

```
public Speisekarte()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

But nothing happens if I click on the button.

If I use a button in the same Form like that its working:

```
public void DateLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Warenkorb.Text = "Test";
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: use debug and see if you method is being called at least - when you click the button. If you are using Visual studio you can F8 to create a break-point in your code.

Comment: I used my Console to see if the button is working. But its not..

Answer (score 0):

The component has changed it's value, if you do a check in your debugger, or just print the value, you will see that the button class did indeed get it's text changed. The problem is, you aren't refreshing the form itself. It was not -redrawn after you changed the form.

Try to refresh/re-paint your form, and you should now see the name.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event and an Eventargs in your UserControl, for example:

```
public partial class Speisekarte : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler<ChangeTextEvenArgs> ChangeText;

    public Speisekarte (  )
    {
        InitializeComponent ( );
    }

    private void Button_Click ( object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        ChangeText?.Invoke ( this, new ChangeTextEvenArgs ( ) { Text = "New Text" } );
    }

    public class ChangeTextEvenArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then in the form, we do a handle to control the event of the UserControl:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ( );
        this.MySpeisekarte.ChangeText += Speisekarte_ChangeText;
    }
    private void Speisekarte_ChangeText ( object sender, Speisekarte.ChangeTextEvenArgs e )
    {
        this.Warenkorb.Text = e.Text;
    }
}
```

This is because you do nt have a Windows instance in your UserControl, but with the event, the form or windows receive the text when it is fired, for this we generate an EventArgs with the properties that we want to pass in the event